# Не ругаться на самоподписанный SSL сертификат в хроме

Tags: nginx, ssl, google-chrome

Для отладки было настроено проксирование в nginx с использованием самоподписанного сертификата. Как заставить Хром перестать ругаться на то что сертификат не доверенный?
С nginx и Хромом можно делать все что потребуется (в разумных пределах конечно).

Comment: Сказать ему, что сертификат хороший. Или добавить в системное хранилище доверенных сертификатов. А хроме: настройки/дополнительно/кнопка настройка сертификатов. Только слепой не заметит или у вас хром не той системы

Comment: воспользуйтесь **не**-самоподписанным сертфикатом. https://www.startssl.com/ https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Sergey, сертификат добавлен в системное хранилище, но Хром продолжает ворчать. Забыл, ОС Вин 7

Comment: Я никогда не выпускал не-самоподписанный сертификат. Нет ли у хрома какой-то настройки, чтоб больше не ругался?

Comment: А что именно он говорит про сертификат ? потому как добавление сертификата как корневого должно было помочь, может у вас имя домена на сертификате не соответствует тому куда идете ? тогда надо как то делать wildcard сертификат или если доменов много и совсем разные - то генерацию сертификатов на лету, так некоторые прокси умеют

Comment: @MiF Может не в тут папку положили? Есть ещё такой вариант. Вы же можете изготовить самодельный корневой сертификат и подписывать им свои самодельные сертификаты. Свой корневой кидаете в папку доверенных корневых центров сертификации и больше никаких проблем. Сам так делал.

Comment: @MiF Программку certmgr.msc знаете же? В какой папке она показывает ваш сертификат? По-моему он должен быть в доверенных лицах или в доверенных корневых

Comment: Глянул какие есть сертификаты в системе и какие в хроме. Хром не признаёт некоторые системные папки. Например доверенных лиц. Похоже он никому не доверяет. Так что сертификат надо кидать в корневые.